# WCF Data Service Query Execution

Tags: wcf-data-services

If i have a query - 
http:///Northwind.svc/Orders?filter=Freight gt 30

I believe, WCF Data Service  query is executed -

1. When entity set is enumerated, such as during a foreach.
2. When the query is assigned to a List collection or First or single is called.
3. When the Execute or BeginExecute method is explicitly called.

My question-
1. If I browse to the above url or

1. If I call the above url using jQuery and enumerate the results.

At what point is my query executed?

I believe in my question #2 it will be executed everytime while enumerating through the results. If so, how do i avoid that so that I get all the results in one network call.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Client-side of WCF Data Services uses restricted LINQ provider to access query results. Similar to other LINQ providers it uses so called deferred query execution, i.e. it doesn't execute the query (which in case of OData is an HTTP call) until it needs results. So it's easy to figure out when the HTTP call occurs. Of course it occurs on calls First(), Single() etc, on aggregation calls such as Count(), on result enumeration.

When it comes to JavaScript and jQuery, then it has nothing to do with client-side of WCF Data Services. I am not a UI developer, but AFAIK jQuery has its own HTTP helper methods, so you have to check how they are implemented. But in general, it you have an OData request, you can't really split its execution: once you send it to an OData feed, you will get back all results. If you need to limit number of results fetched, you can extend the query URI with $count clause.